# Spark saveAsTextFile to Azure Blob creates a blob instead of a text file

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to save an RDD to a text file. My instance of Spark is running on Linux and connected to Azure Blob

```
   val rdd = sc.textFile("wasb:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv")

//find the rows which have only one digit in the 7th column in the CSV
val rdd1 =  rdd.filter(s => s.split(",")(6).length() == 1)

rdd1.saveAsTextFile("wasb:///HVACOut")
```

When I look at the output, it is not as a single text file but as a series of application/octet-stream files in a folder called HVACOut.

How can I output it as a single text file instead?

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure you can get just one file without a directory. If you do

```
rdd1 .coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("wasb:///HVACOut")
```

you will get one file inside a directory called "HVACOut" the file should like something like part-00001. This is because your rdd is a disturbed on in your cluster with what they call partitions. When you do a call to save (all save functions) it is going to make a file per partition. So by call coalesce(1) your telling you want 1 partition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, it creates one file but its NOT a text file. Its still just an application/octet-stream file in a folder called HVACOut. Separately, it created a HVACOut.txt file that has 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

After finished provisioning a Apache Spark cluster on Azure HDInsight, you can go to the built-in **Jupyter notebook** for your cluster at: https://YOURCLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/jupyter.

There you will find sample notebook with example on how to do this.

Specifically, for scala, you can go to the notebook named "**02 - Read and write data from Azure Storage Blobs (WASB) (Scala)**".

Copying some of the code and comments here:

**Note:**

Because CSV is not natively supported by Spark, so there is no built-in way to write an RDD to a CSV file. However, you can work around this if you want to save your data as CSV.
Code:

```
csvFile.map((line) => line.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile("wasb:///example/data/HVAC2sc.csv")
```

Hope this helps!